# Can my friend's Android phone impersonate the starship Enterprise?

Tags: applications, samsung-nexus-s, audio

I was recently browsing Reddit and found the geekiest command to boldly go where no command has gone before.

```
play -n -c1 synth whitenoise lowpass -1 120 lowpass -1 120 lowpass -1 120 gain +14
```

It's a Linux command using the sox package to create a continuous sound loop like the background sound on the starship Enterprise. Are there any existing Android apps for a Samsung Galaxy Nexus phone running Android 4.0.1 that would be able to replicate this?

Comment: Apps that do this will have to be careful with their branding and look and feel, bearing in mind that the Tricorder app was removed from the Market a while ago because it had an "LCARS" interface http://www.eurodroid.com/2011/09/06/android-tricorder-app-pulled-due-to-legal-complaint/ Just using a recorded MP3, just sounds so much easier!

Comment: You could always just "watch" [this YouTube video](http://youtu.be/ZPoqNeR3_UA)

Answer (score 3):

You could just use Audacity or something to create a short clip of white noise, then play that on loop through the phone's media player. However, in my opinion, this whole question is a bad idea. It will constantly be running down your battery and using up processor cycles.

Comment: Its a bit of fun question nothing serious just wondering if there was an audio app that would do the same or similar job as sox on android I'm sure he wouldn't be using it more than if you were to play music for instance on your phone for an hour or 2 btw here is the original request https://plus.google.com/105047371315992982745/posts/5AL9CFCakzy

Answer (score 2):

There is a SoX port for Android available as an open source project on GitHub: https://github.com/Kyborg2011/SoxPlayer

The developer says that it's not stable and uses high amounts of cpu ([source](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=28297416)):

> 1. instability (every tenth run - nothing happens)
> 2. high load on the processor

Wouldn't recommend to run that but theoretically this can be done.